# We have a external .lib that links to Qt5Core.dll but our environment contains Qt5Core_conda.dll

Tags: qt, dll, pyqt5

We have an external library (`Foobar.lib`), provided by a customer, that is linked against `Qt5Core.dll`. We have to use that library in our own code.

In our environment, we use conda and conda-forge provided Qt libraries, and the conda-forge maintainers decided to append the suffix
`_conda` to all the `.lib` and `.dll` files (not sure why), so we end up with `Qt5Core_conda.dll` in our `PATH`.

This is a problem because our runtime either does not find `Qt5Core.dll`, or it loads up `Qt5Core.dll` and `Qt5Core_conda.dll` at the same time, which does not work because globals from one library are not seen by the other (notably the `QApplication` global).

One thing that ocurred to us is to open `Foobar.lib` and manually change the references from `Qt5Core.dll` to `Qt5Core_conda.dll`, however given that the name is *larger* we would need to add new bytes to the file, which would mess up the addresses inside it (we suspect that if we wanted to *reduce* the name it would be possible).

We are looking for a way to update/rewrite `Foobar.lib` to point to `Qt5Core_conda.dll` instead of `Qt5Core.dll`, any suggestions?

Our environment is Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While patching the original library *could* be possible (but only if done with extreme caution and with the correct tools), I wouldn't suggest that.

For a generic case, a logical and simple solution would be to simply *copy* the library using the required name, but this wouldn't probably work properly for Qt for various reasons.

A viable solution is instead to create a *hard link*, which is a dynamic and transparent reference that makes it look like it's the *actual* file, as opposed to the common Windows `lnk` interface. When a hard link is created, the access to the link works *exactly* like accessing the original file: the only difference is the path and file name, but they both refer to the same data object in the file system.

You will need to use the [`mklink` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) in the command prompt, with the `/h` flag (for the hard link) and the *target* path followed by the *source* path:

```
mklink /h "path/to/Qt5Core.dll" "path/to/Qt5Core_conda.dll"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm. Just adding that in our conda env we use a `post-link.bat` script to make this hard link.